# How can i use af:scrollComponentIntoViewBehavior in af:tree?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, managed-bean

How can i use af:scrollComponentIntoViewBehavior in af:tree?

```
 <af:tree value="#{MBMenu.model}" var="node" id="tr1" summary="summary"  initiallyExpanded="true"
                 fetchSize="-1" contentDelivery="immediate" expandAllEnabled="true">
            <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
                <af:link text="#{node.text}" id="cl1">
                    <af:scrollComponentIntoViewBehavior componentId="#{node.action}" focus="true"
                                                        subTargetId="content"/>
                </af:link>
            </f:facet>
        </af:tree>
```

I try the code above but nothing.

But the following code works

```
<af:link text="text" id="cl2">
                    <af:scrollComponentIntoViewBehavior componentId="#{MBMenu.action}" focus="true"
                                                        subTargetId="content"/>


                </af:link>
```

Does somebody get it worked?

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work, the targeted `componentId` had to have the `clientComponent` attribute set to `true`